# In the additive groups $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{R}$, or $\mathbb{C}$ every nonzero (i.e., nonidentity) element has infinite order.

Tags: group-theory

I know the order say m is some integral integer that gives gives an element an identity, say 0 in the additive case. Can somebody give an example as to why it has infinite order? Is that because there is infinity amount of elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Name $G$ one of those groups and take $0 \neq g \in G$. If $g$ has a finite order $n$ we get

$$n \cdot g = (n\cdot 1) \cdot g=0$$

That can't be as those groups do not have zero divisors for the multiplication.

Now regarding your question *Is that because there is infinity amount of elements?*, the answer is negative. A group can have an infinite number of elements but have elements of finite orders. An example is $(\mathbb U, \cdot)$ where $\mathbb U$ is the set of the complex numbers of modulus equal to one endowed with the multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

The order of an element $a$ is by definition is the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $a^n$ is the identity. By convention if $a^n\neq e$ for all positive integers $n$, we say the order is infinity.

Comment: Then why in the additive groups, n doesn't exist?

Comment: Because for all positive integers $n$, adding an element to itself $n$ times will never give you zero.